# How to make a function that iterates an isalpha function work?

Tags: c, string, function

I have a program that compares each element in a string using `isalpha`. I input a string and it calls the function to cycle through the array and check if all characters are letters. If yes, it prints true and false otherwise. My problem is that I can't seem to make it work right. It would only return false every time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isAlpha(char string[]);

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int bool;

    printf("Enter a string to check: \n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    bool = isAlpha(str);
    if(bool != 0)
    {
        printf("True\n");
    }
    else if(bool == 0)
    {
        printf("False\n");
    }
    return 0;   
}

int isAlpha(char string[])
{
    int i, check, len = strlen(string);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(string[i]))
        {
            check = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            check = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user enters `abc`, then the returned string from `fgets` will be `abc\n\0`. In other words, it's the newline character that always fails the `isalpha` test. You can fix the problem by subtracting one from the string length. You should also initialize the `check` variable since it's possible that the body of the loop will never run, e.g. if the user presses enter without typing anything.

```
int i, check = 0;
int len = strlen(string) - 1;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

---

As @ShadowRanger points out in the comments, nothing is simple in C. To be absolutely safe, you should remove the newline from the string as shown below

```
int i, check = 0;
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';
int len = strlen(string);
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Comment: Unconditionally subtracting is going to misbehave if the buffer `fgets` is filling fills before you see a newline. It will `NUL` terminate the buffer, but it won't have a newline, and you'll have skipped an arbitrary character that may be meaningful to the test.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int isAlpha(char string[])
{
    int i = 0, len = strlen(string);
    for(i = 0; isalpha(string[i]); i++); // cycle through string until characters are alphabet characters

    return i == len - 1;
    /* this has to be true if all characters are alpha */
}
```

To solve your issue do:

```
for(i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
```